# Is `<` an unsupported expression in rollupJoin's?

Tags: cube.js

I am trying to use a `rollupJoin` pre-aggregation as per [this example](https://cube.dev/docs/pre-aggregations#rollup-join) but instead of joining on an ID I am attempting to join using dates, i.e. something like:

```js
joins: {
  Weeks: {
    relationship: 'belongsTo',
    sql: `${Weeks.startAt} < ${Event.closedAt} AND ${Event.closedAt} < ${Weeks.endedAt}`
  }
}
```

but am receiving the following error:

```
Error: Error: Internal: SQL error: ParserError("Unsupported expression \'Lt\' in JOIN condition") disabled backtrace
```

I can't find any explicit documentation of these operators not being supported. Are they not supported or am I getting the syntax wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to share the data schemas being used, as well as what database(s) you're using?

Thanks in advance 

Comment: Both the databases are PostgreSQL (v13.1). What data schema information would be useful / how is best to present that information?

Comment: I just wanted to see the schema describing the fields in the join, as well as the `cube.js` configuration file. Also just wanted to confirm that Cube Store was being used.